# How to focus a specific input after window focus on electron

Tags: electron

I'm using electron global shortcuts, and when I use my shortcut to focus my electron app window, i want to focus a specific field to avoid user to click on this field.

```
const shortcut = globalShortcut.register('Control+Shift+T', () => {
  mainWindow.show();
  // How do I focus here on a specific field 
});
```

What is better ? Should i send an event to the app window and listen this event in my app javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I'm doing it is to use a preload script (webPreferences in the options for the window) to add a message handler that you can call from main.  When the window in question gets the 'dom-ready' event, send a message to the window (optionally sending the id of the item on which you want focus) and then just use plain old DOM to call focus() on the element.